# Implement Google Play account settings button

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have implemented signing-in functionnalities in my Android game (which uses libgdx) via the `BaseGameUtils` class, but I saw a neat feature in a game (Jetpack Joyride) that I'd like to reproduce. On their homescreen, if the user is logged in, the "sign in google" button opens the Google Play account's settings (where the user can change his image, sign out and see his Google Play Services version).

I would like to have something similar, but have no idea how to call and open this page. I browsed the whole Google Play documentation but couldn't find anything about it.

What should I use to open this specific page ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you must follow the [branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines) if you want to implement that. See [Building a custom Google Sign-In button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) for more information.

Also, you may want to use the following approaches discussed in [providing a sign-in button](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin#providing_a_sign-in_button):

- Include a [`com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton) on the main activity layout as described in the previous section; or
- Design a custom sign-in button according to the [Google Sign-In branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines).